# How to get rows where two columns values repeat

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table where pair of val1 and val2 can repeat in table.
My goal is to get ids where this pair repeat

From this

| Id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | bbb |
| 2 | bbb | aaa |
| 3 | ccc | aaa |
| 4 | bbb | ccc |
| 5 | ccc | aaa |

To this

| Id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 5 |

Comment: Please do not tag conflicting technologies. SQL Server and MySQL and *completely* different products, and T-SQL is only used by the former. I've removed the tags, you will need to [edit] your question to (re)tag the technology you are using. Also explain the difficulty you are having achieving your goal, or demonstrate your attempts and explain why they aren't working.

Comment: Would (4, ccc, aaa) count as repeated?

Comment: @jigga, not really work for me, i got a empty table

Comment: You've retagged [[tag:tsql]] but not told us what product you are using. T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well. You also forgot to address the rest of my comment about your attempts/difficulty.

Comment: Id 3 and 5 have the same values so why is 3 expected and 5 is not?

Comment: Why does the row with an ID of `4` appear? There are no other rows with `bbb` and `ccc`? Why does `3` appear and `5` does not, even though the values for `Val1` and `Val2` are identical? Your latest edit makes this more confusing.

Comment: @Stu. has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select t1.id from myTable t1 
 inner join myTable t2 on t1.id <> t2.id and
((t1.val1 = t2.val2 and t1.val2 = t2.val1) or 
 (t1.val1 = t2.val1 and t1.val2=t2.val2));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest version of SQL Server you could utilise a windowed count of greatest/least:

```
select id 
from (
    select id, count(*) over( partition by greatest(val1,val2), least(val1, val2)) cnt
    from t
)t
where cnt > 1;
```

[demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XhcmSPb_)

For earlier versions you can replace the functions with case expressions to accomplish the same:

```
select id 
from (
    select id, count(*) over( partition by case when val2 > val1 then val2 else val1 end, case when val2 > val1 then val1 else val2 end) cnt
    from t
)t
where cnt > 1;
```